# Australian applying for a UK Visa

Tags: visas, air-travel, uk, australia, london

I am applying for a 2-year UK visa. I am a little confused with the checklist of documents to have before my appointment. It is asking for evidence of travel, flights, itinerary. However I don't want to book my flight prior to getting my visa.

Do I have to book a flight first? If so, can it be a one-way ticket?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> It is asking for evidence of travel, flights, itinerary

Just a plan of your travel. Do not buy any paid tickets or pay for hotel reservations before you get your Visa; Works against you.